# How to avoid "Proceed with this action? [y/N]" of pkg?

Tags: freebsd

Or: What's the equivalent of `apt-get install --yes` in FreeBSD's `pkg`?

I know about `yes | pkg install ...`, but an option seems to be much more conveniant and savely avoids answering `y` to questions during eventual installation and configuration routines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pkg install -y <package>
```

See [the manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg-install&sektion=8&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.1-RELEASE+and+Ports) for details.

Comment: Thank you. I assumed that if `man pkg install` wouldn't open the manual of `pkg-install` it's wouldn't be available, but one has to use `man pkg-install`.